# Optimise Select Query containing inner join

Tags: mysql, optimization

Mysql Version - `5.5.39`

I have these two tables `Bugs` and `BugStatus`

I want to fetch the `Open` and `Closed` bug counts for a given user.

I am currently using this query

```
SELECT BugStatus.name, 
    count(BugStatus.name) AS count 
FROM bugs 
INNER JOIN BugStatus ON bugs.status = bugstatus.id 
WHERE bugs.assignee='irakam' 
GROUP BY bugstatus.name;
```

Now let's assume I am going to have 100,000 rows in my `Bugs` table. Does this query still stand or how should I modify it. I did use `Explain` but  I am still confused. So can this query be optimised?

SQLFiddle link - [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78f15/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  bs.name,
        count(*) as count  -- simply count(*) unless you are avoiding nulls
    from  bugs
    inner join  BugStatus AS bs  ON bugs.status = bs.id
    where  bugs.assignee='irakam'
    group by  bs.name;

bugs:  INDEX(assignee)  -- since filtering occurs first
```

[*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can further optimize your table by creating an index on bugs.status and bugs.assignee:

`CREATE INDEX idx_bugs_assignee_status on bugs(assignee, status);`

As far as the execution plan goes:

> Select Type: Simple

This means you are executing a simple query, without any subqueries or unions.

> Type: ALL

This means that you are doing a full-table scan is being done on the bug status table (every row is inspected), should be avoided for large tables, but this is ok for the BugStatus table, since it only contains 2 rows.

> Type: ref

This means all rows with the matching index values are read from the Bugs table, for each combination of rows found in BugStatus.

> possible_keys

This lists out the possible indexes that might be used to answer your query (The primary key of BugStatus, and the foreign key on bugs.status)

> Key

This is the actual index that the optimizer chose to answer your query (none in the case of the BugStatus table, since a full-table scan is being performed on it, and the foreign key on status in the case of the bugs table.)

> ref

This shows the index that was used on the joined table to compare results.

> rows

This column indicates the number of rows that were examined.

> extra: Using temporary; Using filesort

'Using temporary' means that mysql needs to create a temporary table to sort your results, which is done because of your GROUP BY clause.
'Using filesort' this means the database had to perform an another pass over your results to figure out how to retrieve the sorted rows.

> extra: Using where

Means you had a WHERE clause in your query.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html